# Plot Loss vs epochs History for test and training set

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, plot, loss

I'm using [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) 2.4.0 and [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) to plot `Loss` vs `epochs` history for the test and training set. I was able to do it when I was using [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) 1.1.5, using the code below; however, when trying to shift it to the new version, it doesn't work

```py
model.fit(X2_train ,y2_train, epochs =100, batch_size = 32)
```

```py
plt.subplot(1,1,1)
plt.plot(model.history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(model.history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Loss function of CNN Model')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper right')
plt.ylim(0,200)
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, bottom=0.0, right=2.0, top=0.8, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what's your main issue. The code works in tf 1 but not in tf 2? Give some reproducible code.

Comment: yes it is working in tf 1 and not in tf 2

Comment: Provided information is not sufficient. Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: This could be the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847576/keyerror-val-loss-when-training-model) or I assume that the problem is what you define as metric in `model.compile( metrics=["ACC"])` like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68979038/10452700)

Answer (score 1):

Credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65046881/10452700) you can plot the graphs with the *available metrics* of the history for all datasets of the `history.history`:

```py
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), shuffle=True)

...

pd.DataFrame(history.history).plot(figsize=(8,5))
plt.show()
```

you can also save/log it. there nice workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41061457/keras-how-to-save-the-training-history-attribute-of-the-history-object).