# KeyError: 'val_loss' and KeyError: 'val_iou_score'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a model using a set of images Unet. 
It saved the .HDF5 file, but gave the error below when I tried to draw the loss and accuracy graphs.

```
KeyError: 'val_loss'
```

My Keras version = 2.5.0 and Tensorflow version = 2.5.0

Below is the code I used.

```
########### Additional code lines ###############

# define model
model = sm.Unet(BACKBONE, encoder_weights='imagenet', 
                input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS),
                classes=n_classes, activation='softmax')
model.compile('Adam', loss=sm.losses.categorical_focal_jaccard_loss, metrics=[sm.metrics.iou_score])
#Train the model. 
history=model.fit(train_img_gen,
          steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
          epochs=2,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=val_img_gen,
          validation_steps=val_steps_per_epoch)

model.save('landcover_25_epochs_RESNET_backbone_batch16.hdf5')

#plot the training and validation IoU and loss at each epoch
loss = history.history['loss']
print("loss = ",loss)
val_loss = history.history['val_loss'] #Line 1
epochs = range(1, len(loss) + 1)
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'y', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

acc = history.history['iou_score'] 
val_acc = history.history['val_iou_score'] #Line 2

plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'y', label='Training IoU')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r', label='Validation IoU')
plt.title('Training and validation IoU')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('IoU')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Line 1 gives `KeyError: 'val_loss'` error and Line 2 gives `KeyError: 'val_iou_score'` error.

Error in Line 1 is below.

[image]

Kindly note that I trained the model for just 2 epochs to check if it works fine.

Could someone kindly tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try printing `history.history` and you will see that the keys throwing `KeyError` are not present in that dictionary.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I got this when I print history.history : {'loss': [0.9634058475494385, 0.8864547610282898], 'iou_score': [0.10013526678085327, 0.14829683303833008]} Where are val_loss and the val_iou_score values?

Comment: yes, those keys are missing from `history.history` dictionary, so you would have to figure out why

Comment: you model is not doing validation, try to print val_steps_per_epoch, the problem is in fit in the val_img_gen, maybe for some reason val_steps_per_epoch is set to None or zero

Answer (score 0):

Specify `metrics=[“accuracy”]` in the `model.compile()`, then the history object will have the keys as ‘accuracy’ and ‘val_accuracy’. While if you specify it as `metrics=[“acc”]` then they will be reported with the keys `‘acc’` and `‘val_acc’`.

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer=opt, metrics=["acc"])
 
...
 
plt.figure(1)

# summarize history for accuracy

plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
```